# Nullable type still throw nullpointer exception at Kotlin

Tags: nullpointerexception, kotlin, null-pointer

This code below throw nullpointer exception in third line. Because objectHashMap is null. But how is that possible. Its a nullable type and it can be null.

```
val objectsGTypeInd = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Post>>() {}
val objectHashMap: HashMap<String, Post>? = dataSnapshot?.getValue(objectsGTypeInd)
val postList = ArrayList<Post>(objectHashMap?.values)
```

"collection == null" message writing at logcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `ArrayList<Post>(null)`, you'll get this problem. If your `objectHashMap` is null, or it contains no values, you'll have a null there. The compiler isn't really complaining about you having a null, it's complaining about the fact that you're passing it to the `ArrayList()` constructor.

If you look at the JavaDoc for `ArrayList`, it states that the collection can't be null, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
>  * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
>  * iterator.
>  *
>  * @param c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
>  * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
>  */
> ```

Comment: Not to question your answer, just wanted to point out that when a map has no values, `values()` would likely return an empty `Collection` instead of `null`.

Comment: True, but if the collection you are calling `.values` on is null in the first place, you'll get null. Because there's no reference to call `.values` on, the call won't get made, and the whole expression would evaluate to null.

Comment: Oh that's absolutely correct. I was referring only to the "or it contains no values" part.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `objectHashMap?.values` evaluates to `null` when:

1. `objectHashMap` itself is `null` or
2. `values` property is `null`

You’re using the safe operator `?.` and this can obviously lead to `null` results which you shouldn’t pass to an ArrayList. You could provide a default value using the Elvis operator:

```
ArrayList<Post>(objectHashMap?.values ?: defaultValues)
```

Alternatively, an empty list can be created like this:

```
if(objectHashMap==null) ArrayList<Post>() else ArrayList<Post>(objectHashMap.values)
```

Note that in the second part, the compiler lets you use `objectHashMap` as a non-nullable type since you checked it in the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin docs state:

`b?.length`

> This returns b.length if b is not null, and null otherwise.

Thus, you might be calling `ArrayList<Post>(null)` since `objectHashMap: HashMap<String, Post>?` is of [type nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) due to the question mark at the end `?`.

From the [Kotlin docs about ArrayList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html#arraylist), which link us to [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) `Class ArrayList<E>` and the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) you're using:

`public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` states:

> Throws:
>   NullPointerException - if the specified collection is null